# Compiler randomly throwing different errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm getting different errors each time I compile my C project. There are 3 sets of them that randomly appear during the building process, and all of them are

```
syntax error before 'foo'
```

or

```
syntax error before 'foo' token.
```

They happen in different files and there are no obvious syntax errors there.

I'm using Windows 7, Eclipse with the C/C++ plugin to make a C project and gcc 3.4.5 (mingw- vista special r3). The following flags are being used:

```
-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

I've checked and rechecked all my files for preprocessor syntax errors, but found nothing.

What kind of mistakes in my source code can be generating this strange behavior? How can I avoid this kind of headaches in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, it was a mutual "include" statement.

Client.h included Cashier.h which also included Client.h...

Apparently this can generate syntax errors at completely unrelated lines (or even files!).

Comment: This is why you need to use include guards. You also need to try not to do that, as this can in principle cause a stack overflow in the C preprocessor.